# Changing the position of a picture at run time in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there any way to change the position of a picture at run time in Crystal Report through conditional formatting or something like that?

thanks

Comment: Do you want pixel-perfect positioning, or just to be able to print it in one of two specific places?

Comment: I am gonna to align some logos in the upper right of my report at run time. so I place an empty picture on my report and set it's graphic location. but because the pictures don't have the same size, some of them go beyond of the report area.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the x-axis position (as is the case with most other fields) by right-clicking on the picture, selecting 'Size and Position' and entering a formula for "X:" that returns a number as the position.

If that's not enough control, you can add multiple copies of the picture to your report anywhere you may want them to appear. Then, conditionally suppress those that are not in the position you want on the final report run via a suppression formula.

Comment: @Rayan: when I right click on the picture and go into the picutre tab, there are four group box including crop form, scaling, size and orginal size. but there is no any button for entering a formula for them. I use crystal report 2010.

Comment: @VahidGhadiri It's not under "Format Graphic...", just right-click and hit "Size & Position"