# change field's position dynamically in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

how can i  change field's position dynamically in crystal report?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the position of a picture at run time in Crystal Report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312175/changing-the-position-of-a-picture-at-run-time-in-crystal-report)

Answer (score 2):

See this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8312175/403572). Although it addresses repositioning an *image* dynamically, the same thing will work for most fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
ReportName RR=new ReportName();
RR.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects[Name].Top=1000;
RR.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects[Name].Left=1000;
```

at the end set crystalReportViewer's ReportSource to RR.